# How do I detach a listener defined in another scope?

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have defined a listener in the `viewWillAppear()` function, and am trying to remove/detach it in the `viewWillDisappear` function. However, I am unable to access the listener in the `viewWillDisappear()` function, so am unable to use `.remove()` to detach it.

My code:

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(true)

     let db = Firestore.firestore()
     let docRef = db.collection("collection").document("document")

    let listener = docRef.addSnapshotListener { (querySnapshot, errur) in
     ....
     }
}




 override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    listener.remove() //ERROR: Use of unresolved identifier 'listener'
}
```

I realise that the error is because "listener" was defined in another scope, but how can I still access it to remove it in the `viewWillDisappear()` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
private var listener: ListenerRegistration?

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(true)

    let db = Firestore.firestore()
    let docRef = db.collection("collection").document("document")

    listener = docRef.addSnapshotListener { (querySnapshot, errur) in
         // ....
     }
}

override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    // always call super.viewWillDisappear also.
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
    listener.remove() //ERROR: Use of unresolved identifier 'listener'
    listener = nil
}
```

Comment: Hey, thanks. Just for future reference for people who have the same issue, I believe the type is 'ListenerRegistration'.